# Is the thunderbolt 2 port reversible?

Tags: thunderbolt

Although i am able to plug thunderbolt 2 and mini displayport devices into my macbook pro either way. They only seem to function if i plug them in one way and not the other. 
I was wondering if my macbook is defective and that the connector is reversible? or not?

If not can you please elaborate on why a connector design that allows for a cable to be plugged in upside down is used?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mini-DP is not meant to go in either way up, it's strictly a one-way-up connection - like USB, not like Lighting.

If you made it fit upside down, then excessive force was used & the socket is distorted.

[image]

Ref: Wikipedia - [Mini DisplayPort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mini_DisplayPort)

Comment: my port seems to not be distorted and is a lot more round than that but i can see what you mean. thank you for taking your time to write an answer

Answer (score 0):

thunderbolt is inverted into the MAC book pro to fit internal electronic components, so your adapters will only work inverted (upside down). mini display port on macs (if applicable) only allow one way to connect.